# Ubuntu 12.04 and Realtek Wireless Card Incompatible

Tags: 12.04, wireless, realtek

Quick background: I installed Linux Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Inspiron 3520 after uninstalling Windows 8.  A friend suggested to do this as opposed to buying a laptop with Linux pre-installed.  Everything except the wireless card works.

When I load up the laptop, I see a wireless animation as if it's trying to locate the wireless connection (for a while, then it goes blank), but no connections appear under the wireless option (under "Edit Connections" then "Wireless").

What I've tried:
- Doing ndiswrapper.  Failed.
- Installing a few kernels for realtek.  Failed.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with RTL8187SE wireless NIC.  The problem was because of the default driver r8187se is buggy.  For me ndiswrapper solved the problem, but I had to blacklist the original driver (yours will be different from r8187se).  After I blacklisted the original driver, and enabled ndiswrapper at the startup, everything is fine now.  You can see my post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214085/need-a-few-reboots-to-connect-to-wireless).